# Qual programa usar para comparar o desempenho das maquinas virtuais?

Tags: linux, virtualbox, vmware

Estou querendo fazer teste de memoria, processamento, rede e etc... nas maquinas virtuais: VMWare, Virtual PC e VirtualBox utilizando o sistema hospedeiro windows e não sei que programa pode me auxiliar nesta questão, quero fazer uma comparação para certificar com base nos dados qual seria a melhor delas.

http:// www.techtudo.com.br/artigos/noticia/2013/05/vmware-ou-virtualbox-qual-o-melhor-programa-para-criar-maquina-virtual.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recomendo que utilize o [Phoronix Test Suite](http://www.phoronix-test-suite.com/).

Ele é um sistema open source para benchmarking automatizados, permitindo a execução de dezenas (se não centenas) de benchmarks sem praticamente nenhuma intervenção do usuário.

Ele realiza benchmarks de vários tipos, como disco, sistema de arquivos, banco de dados, computação na GPU, gráficos, consumo de energia e outros mais.

Ele na verdade simplesmente automatiza e gera relatórios a partir dos resultados de benchmarks que já existem, como o DB Bench, IO Zone, etc.

Além disso, você pode postar os resultados do benchmark e comparar com outros resultados no site [OpenBenchmarking.org](https://openbenchmarking.org/).

Seria ótimo compartilhar os resultados obtidos. Eu mesmo muito me interesso por estes benchmarks e gostaria muito de realizá-los, mas ultimamente ando completamente sem tempo para me dedicar a isto.